# batch file not sending serial commands

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that I would like to send commands to the serial port, COM1.  I have the following, and I can see it setup the port properly. But it stops there, after it sets up the serial port, it doesn't send any commands.

```
@ echo off
color b0
cls
echo.
echo.      
echo. Enter IP address of the CSR on the site.
echo. Example: 11.152.34.82
set /p IP="IP Address: "
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a in ("%IP%") do (
echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d
set last=%%d
set first=%%a
set second=%%b
set third=%%c
)
pause
cls
echo. select the technology you are trying to restore
echo. 1: AWS
echo. 2: PCS
echo. 3: LTE 1
echo. 4: LTE 2
set /p tech="Enter number: "
if "%tech%"=="1" goto AWS 
if "%tech%"=="2" goto PCS
if "%tech%"=="3" goto LTE1
if "%tech%"=="4" goto LTE2
echo. Not found
goto commonexit

:AWS
set /a z=%last% - 2
set /a y=%last% - 25
goto UMTSScript

:PCS
set /a z=%last% -3
set /a y=%last% - 24
goto UMTSScript

:UMTSScript
mode COM1 BAUD=9600 Parity=n DATA=8
echo. command1 > COM1
echo. command2 > COM1
```

Comment: Perhaps the command is not understood because it's preceded by a space? Try `echo command1 > COM1` instead of `echo.`.

Comment: Give this a try: `set /p "=COMMAND1"<nul>\\.\COM1`

Comment: Please read this help topic: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the script, first line:

```
@echo off
```

Then I would try:

```
@echo command1>COM1
@echo command2>COM1
```

If that doesn't work, I would try:

```
@echo command1|COM1
@echo command2|COM1
```

Answer (score 0):

redirecting to the COM port this way *should* work..
what does the output of `mode COM1 /status` say after the script runs? is handshaking on unexpectedly?

also, be mindful of ANSI/Unicode mode in cmd.exe itself.. here you can see the unicode flavor creates text files twice as large as the ansi flavor.. perhaps you're transmitting a bunch of NUL's that you werent aware of :)

```
    C:\>cmd /u /c "(echo 12345678>test.txt) && (for %a in (test.txt) do @echo %~za bytes)"
    20 bytes
    
    C:\>cmd /a /c "(echo 12345678>test.txt) && (for %a in (test.txt) do @echo %~za bytes)"
    10 bytes
```